# barchart using rechart rendering background when mouseover on the bars

Tags: reactjs, recharts

normally in barchart using rechart, a "grey background "which covers right and  left side and above of the bars is rendered as well as the tooltip when mouseover on a bar. in mycase, it's not and i am stuck on this issue.[image: what it's needed to be rendered] and here is what is rendered now: [image: what my code renders].
if i read the documentation of recharts here: [recharts bar link](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/BarChart), this "grey shadow" appears by default whezn we pass the mouse on a bar. in my case, it's not. i know i have used a customtooltip and i did because when i was using the regular tooltip, i had to face a huge issue with the data displayed in the tooltip.

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    import { getUserActivity } from "../../../dataManager/dataManager";
    import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
    import {   BarChart, XAxis, YAxis, Tooltip, Bar, Legend, CartesianGrid } from "recharts";
    import "./DailyActivityChart.css";
    
    const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload }) => {
      if (active && payload && payload.length) {
        const weight = payload.find((item) => item.name === "Poids (Kg)");
        const calories = payload.find((item) => item.name === "Calories brûlées (kcal)");
    
        return (
          <div className="daily-custom-tooltip">
            <span className="tooltip-value">{weight.value} kg</span>
            <span className="tooltip-value">{calories.value} kcal</span>
          </div>
        );
      }
      return null;
    };
    
    
    
    
    
    function CustomLegendIcon(props) {
      const { x, y, width, height, size, fill } = props;
      return (
        <svg width={width} height={height} x={x} y={y}>
          <g className="legend-icon">
            <circle cx={size / 2} cy={size / 2} r={size / 2 - 1} fill={fill} />
          </g>
        </svg>
      );
    }
    /**
     * DailyActivityChart component displays a bar chart showing daily activity for a user.
     * @returns {JSX.Element}
     */
    function DailyActivityChart() {
      // Extract userId from the URL using useParams
      const { userId } = useParams();
      // Initialize state variables for user activity and error status
      const [userActivity, setUserActivity] = useState(null);
      const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    
    //
      const [hoveredBarIndex, setHoveredBarIndex] = useState(null);
    //
      // Fetch user activity data when the component mounts or when userId changes
      useEffect(() => {
        /**
         * Fetches user activity data and updates the state.
         * @async
         */
        async function fetchData() {
          try {
            // Get user activity data from the data manager
            const chartData = await getUserActivity(userId);
            // Update the userActivity state with the fetched data
            setUserActivity(chartData);
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            setError(true);
          }
        }
        // Call fetchData to fetch user activity data
        fetchData();
      }, [userId]);
      // If there was an error while fetching data, display an error message
      if (error) {
        return <div>Error: Failed to load user data for activity chart.</div>;
      }
      // If user activity data is not yet loaded, display a loading message
      if (!userActivity) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
      }
      // Format the label for X axis of the chart
      const formatLabel = (value, index) => {
        if (!userActivity || userActivity.length === 0) {
          return "";
        }
        return index + 1;
      };
      // Return the chart
      return (
        <div className="Daily">
          <BarChart
            width={835}
            height={320}
            data={userActivity}
                  >
            <CartesianGrid className="DailyGrid" vertical={false} strokeDasharray="2 2" stroke="grey" />
           
           
            <Bar
              dataKey="kilograms"
              fill="#E6000"
              barSize={7}
              name="Poids (Kg)"
              radius={[3, 3, 0, 0]}
              yAxisId="KilogramsLeft"
            
    
            />
            <Bar
              dataKey="calories"
              barSize={7}
              name="Calories brûlées (kcal)"
              radius={[3, 3, 0, 0]}
              legendIcon={<CustomLegendIcon />}
              yAxisId="CaloriesRight"
           
          
            />
            <text className="Activite" x={90} y={40} textAnchor="middle" fontWeight={600} fontSize={15}>
              Activité quotidienne
            </text>
            <XAxis dataKey="day"
              tickCount={10}
              tickFormatter={formatLabel}
              tickLine={false}
              className="DailyXAxis"
            />
            <YAxis
              orientation="right"
              dataKey="kilograms"
              domain={["dataMin - 1", "dataMax + 2"]}
              ticks={[60, 70, 80]}
              tickFormatter={(value) => `${value} `}
              yAxisId="KilogramsLeft"
              axisLine={false}
              tickLine={false}
              tick={{
                stroke: "#999",
                strokeWidth: 0.1
              }}
            />
    
            <YAxis
              orientation="right"
              dataKey="calories"
              tickCount={10}
              tickFormatter={(value) => `${value} `}
              domain={[0, "dataMax + 50"]}
              hide={true}
              yAxisId="CaloriesRight"
            />
    
            <Tooltip
              content={<CustomTooltip />}
            />
            <Legend
              verticalAlign="top"
              align="right"
              iconType="circle"
              label={{ fontSize: 24, fontWeight: 500 }}
              wrapperStyle={{ color: "black", top: 0 }}
              payload={[
                {
                  value: "Poids (Kg)",
                  type: "circle",
                  color: "#000000",
                },
                {
                  value: "Calories brûlées (kcal)",
                  type: "circle",
                  color: "#E60000",
                },
              ]}
            />
          </BarChart>
        </div>
      );
    }
    // Define PropTypes for the component
    DailyActivityChart.propTypes = {
      userId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    };
    
    export default DailyActivityChart;
```

```
    .DailyTitle {
      font-size: 15px;
      line-height: 24px;
      font-weight: 600;
      margin-top: 50px;
    }
    
    .titleChart {
      font-size: 15px;
      line-height: 24px;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    .recharts-legend-item-text {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 500;
      color: black !important;
    }
    
    .Daily {
      margin-top: 100px;
      background: #FBFBFB;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    
    }
    
    .recharts-legend-item {
      fill: black !important;
      color: black ! important;
    }
    
    path[name="Calories brûlées (kcal)"] {
      fill: red;
    }
    
    .recharts-legend-item.legend-item-1 path {
      fill: red;
    }
    
    .recharts-legend-item-icon[name="Poids (Kg)"] circle {
      fill: black !important;
    }
    
    .recharts-cartesian-grid-horizontal line:hover {
      stroke: rgba(23, 183, 66, 0.5);
      stroke-width: 100%;
      pointer-events: all;
    }
    
    .DailyGrid line {
      stroke-width: 100%;
    }
    
    .DailyXAxis .recharts-cartesian-axis-tick-value {
      font-size: 12px;
      font-weight: 500;
      color: black;
      fill: black;
    }
    
    .recharts-tooltip-wrapper {
      pointer-events: none;
      visibility: visible !important;
      display: flex;
      border: red;
    }
    
    .daily-custom-tooltip {
      background-color: red;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 1.5;
      color: white;
      width: 39px;
      height: 63px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-around;
      border: red !important;
      ;
    }
    
    .recharts-tooltip-wrapper {
      border: none !important;
    }
    .tooltip-value {
      writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
      background-color: red;
      font-size: 7px;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    .label {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .chart-title {
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .recharts-legend-wrapper {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .Daily .recharts-cartesian-grid-horizontal line:not(:last-of-type):not(:nth-of-type(4)) {
      stroke: black !important;
    }
```